# Redirect visitors from my page to other domain(eshop) and redirect them back after purchasing a product?

Tags: php, javascript, redirect

i dont know where else to put this question so here it is:

Lets say there is allready an eshop built. Now im making a site with a link to that specific eshop. Client asked me, if its possible to built the link somehow so when users click on it, they are taken to the eshop and if they optionally make a purchase there, redirect them back to my page? And ofcourse i dont have access to the source of that eshop(where i could easily redirect them to my page after a purchase).

thank you very much!

Comment: Do you have ANY access to the eshop code? If not, it seems to me like a mission impossible

Answer (score 2):

You could send the return url on querystring but if the third party eshop doesn't have any logic to redirect back, it's useless.

Answer (score 1):

Are you owner both sites,too ?

if you owner both, you can pass encoded url of first site by querystring.

First Site Link:

http://www.secondsite.com/?returl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.firstsite.com%2Fpage.html

Second site:

encode returl and use this url anywhere

**Edit: "decode returl and use this url anywhere"**